# C++ Pasar un arreglo de cadenas 2D a una función

Tags: c++, array, string, funciones, puntero-a-función

Estoy tratando de pasar un arreglo de dimensión 2D a una función. 
Mi arreglo es el siguiente:

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
string array[y+1][x+1];
```

Ahora la función

```
void space(int y, int x, string temp[][y+1]);
```

Cuándo la llamo

```
space(y, x, array);
```

También he tratado con

```
void space(string (&temp)[y+1][x+1]){};


void space(string (*temp)[x+1]){};
```

¿Pero nada funciona, alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿ Podrías indicar los errores que estás obteniendo ? Para completar la pregunta :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
string array[y+1][x+1];
```

Esto se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y no es una característica admitida por el estándar de c++. Algunos compiladores y extensiones lo soportan, pero no deberias usarlo.

Se denomina VLA porque la dimensión del array es dinámica  (no conocida en tiempo de compilación) y no haces uso de memoria dinámica para su gestión.

El programa falla porque las funciones sí que requieren (al tratarse de una matriz) que les facilites en tiempo de compilación una de las dos dimensiones.

```
void space(int y, int x, string temp[][y+1]);
//                                     ^^^
//                tiene que ser conocido al compilar
```

La solución pasa por crear la matriz con memoria dinámica, en cuyo caso debes usar un puntero doble:

```
string** array = new string*[x];
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
  array[x] = new string[y];

void space(int y, int x, string **temp);
```